# How do I convert a database from format iso to db3?

Tags: sql, database, converters, iso

How do I export a database from [Isis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDS_ISIS) to [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)?

I can export the database from Isis to iso. I believe that I could convert iso to [dBase 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase#dBase_III) and then [dBase 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBase#dBase_III) to [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), but I haven't found a way to do this yet.

Comment: You can export in comma delimited ASCII files using the print dialog box.This can then be imported to SQL . See `http://portal.unesco.org/ci/en/ev.php-URL_ID=13332&URL_DO=DO_TOPIC&URL_SECTION=201.html `

Comment: Thanks a lot, this could be the best way to solve the problem. I'll try

Comment: @davidstrachan the link you posted is broken, it now takes you to [UNESCO](http://www.unesco.org/new/en/).

Comment: I don't think the 5 links to wikipedia are helpful here. No one should need an explanation of what SQL Server or dBASE 3 are, and if they need it they can Google it. So we can remove about 60% of your question, leaving the first sentence with only the Isis link being meaningful. Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: Try this link http://portal.unesco.org/ci/en/ev.php-URL_ID=13332&URL_DO=DO_TOPIC&URL_SECTION=201.html  Formating seems to cause a problem

Answer (score 1):

1) Use one of the following two lines - the 2nd (MODE) if you have repeatable subfields:

```
'"',v10,'","',v20,'"'/ 
mhl,'"',v10,'","',v20,'"'/
```

2) Save this format and use it to print to a file through the standard PRINT option (Menu database -> print)

3) Choose “Output to: ASCII file (Windows)” and select the correct print format from the list. Then click “Print”.

4) Give a name to the TXT file and click OK.

5) Either:

A) Run MS Excel and open the TXT file. Then [import the data from Excel to SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686), OR

B) Load the flat file [directly into SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

Answered with help from David Strachnan's comment and the [UNESCO CDS/ISIS FAQ](http://portal.unesco.org/ci/en/ev.php-URL_ID=13332&URL_DO=DO_TOPIC&URL_SECTION=201.html)